# Run popup message in protected excel sheet when the value of two cells are equal

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I want to confirm with a popup message and sound effect in a protected Excel 2010 worksheet when the values of two cells are the same. I have tried this formula in data validation:

```
IF(D4=D5,beepnow(),"")
```

but it does not run. Can anyone assist with the formula or a VBA code replacement instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a program that will run whenever you change to the worksheet... which may get pretty annoying... You should get the idea though and be able to modify it to fit your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
If Range("D4").Value = Range("D5").Value Then
    Beep
    MsgBox "Equal", vbInformation, "Check"
End If

End Sub
```

You should just be able to copy and paste it into your worksheet class.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the VB COde Window, select the relevant sheet, you can have the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Range("D4:D4").Cells(1, 1)) = Range("D5:D5").Cells(1, 1))  Then
MsgBox ("Hi")

End If
End Sub
```

The worksheet activate will run the code when you select this sheet.

The Worksheet_change will run the code when you make a change in this sheet.

IF you want to have the check only when D4/D5 is modified

```
If Target.Address = "$D$4" Or Target.Address = "$D$5" Then
If (Range("D4:D4").Cells(1, 1)) = Range("D5:D5").Cells(1, 1))  Then
MsgBox ("Hi")
End If
End If
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: Beep sound and popup message works in unprotected excel sheet with no cross linked cells, but does not work in my master workbook which is protected and has referenced cells from  multiple workbooks